# Http post request with body parameters not working

Tags: networking, flutter

Recently I started developing a small application in Flutter. I have an issue with making a network request. I have tried the call in postman and there it work. But in Flutter I never managed to make it work, I have spent like 3 hours trying to understand what I am doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 @override
  Future<String> login(common.LoginParameters loginParameters) async {
    try {

      final String loginURL = "https://test.example.eu/api/login";

      LoginModel loginResult;

      Map bodyParams = { "inlognaam" : loginParameters.username , "wachtwoord" : loginParameters.password, "code" : loginParameters.smsCode};

      //await API call
      http.Response httpResponse = await http.put( loginURL, body: json.encode(bodyParams));

      if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON
        loginResult=  LoginModel.fromJson(json.decode(httpResponse.body));
      } else {
        // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
        throw Exception('Failed to load post');
      }

      // if logged in get token, Otherwise return error
      if (loginResult.ingelogd) {
        // read the token

        saveToken(loginResult.response);
        return "Ingelogd";
      } else {
        return loginResult.error;
      }
    }
    on Exception catch(error) {
      print("Todor " + error.toString());
      return "Controleer uw internet verbinding en probeer opnieuw";
    }
  }
```

In Postman if I select Post request with body parameters 
inlognaam : someUsername
wachtwoord : somePassword
code : someCode

Then I get a success response

Answer (score 0):

I pass the parameters in the following way, maybe it can work for you:

```
var response = await http.post(
url,
headers:{ "Accept": "application/json" } ,
body: { "state": 1}, //key value
encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")
);
```

Another thing, you say that in postman you make a post request, but in your code you have a put request, verify what is the correct method